# Espresso - Radio button, how to choose data

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm using espresso for testing my android app.
I have a radio group in my layout file

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_number_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>
```

And radio button is added programmatically.
The data is fetched from an API and added!!

```
if (mvns.size() > 0) {
        radioGroup.removeAllViews();
        for (String s : mvns) {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
            RadioGroup.LayoutParams lp = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           // rb.setId(R.id.radio_number_button);
            lp.setMargins(20, 10, 0, 40);
            rb.setLayoutParams(lp);
            rb.setChecked(false);
            String number = Utils.formatNumber(s, countryCode);
            rb.setText(number.replaceAll(" ", "-"));
            rb.setTextSize(16);
            rb.setTag(s);
            rb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            rb.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 50);
            rb.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.division_view_background));
            rb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.radio_button_selector);
            rb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            radioGroup.addView(rb);
        }
```

So, while testing using espresso I tried by setting ID, I got an error! meaning is same ID set to all radioButtons ( I have 5 data in my list).

How do I write test cases for this??

Comment: Where do you set id ?

Comment: what are you trying to test? and what did you try?

Comment: @VinayakB if you can notice I have commented this line rb.setId(R.id.radio_number_button)

Comment: @Be_Negative I have an activity with radioGroup(in layout xml file) and radioButtons are coded programatically as I have posted in the question. The data comes from server (retrofit) and populated to radioButton. In my test I need to select one and press a button to goto next activity!

Comment: You can't set id like that. the id's should be unique for all radio group

Comment: Absolutely right! so how do I write espresso test case in my case?